# Why does PDFBox "moveTextPositionByAmount(X,Y)" result in a exponential behavior?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using the **PDFBox** library and currently I don't understand the behavior of the `moveTextPositionByAmount(X,Y)` method.

Here is the code I am using:

```
[...]    
int i = 0;
        for (InventoryItem currInvItem : invList) {
            try {
                content.moveTextPositionByAmount(textPositionX, textPositionY);
                content.drawString(currInvItem.toString());
                textPositionY = textPositionY+10;
                i++;
                if (i > 10) {
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
[...]
```

This simply goes through a list and prints the elements into my PDF file. I expected the `moveTextPositionByAmount(X,Y)` method to simply move the cursor to another position by some amount in a linear way.

Unfortunately this is not the case and results in a PDF file that has the text in it but the **distance between text elements increases with every iteration** of the loop even though I just increase my variable `textPositionY` by 10. The increase in distance between elements is best described with something like `distance = e^x`

Here is a simplified example output:

[image: Example]

Comment: and how does the content of your pdf file look like for this section of code?

Comment: I have edited my question, I have given you an image as an example.

Comment: N.B. Exponential `e^x` != Quadratic `x^2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`moveTextPositionByAmount()` does not take absolute coordinates as parameters. It's relative positioning.

Let's say you start at coordinates 0 0 and `textPositionY` was initialized with 10. Your first call of the method would move the cursor to 0 10.

The next iteration raises `textPositionY` to 20. You are already at 0 10 but move the cursor by 20, so you are at 0 30.

3rd: 0 60
4th: 0 100
5th: 0 150

If you want equal distances then don't increase `textPositionY` and maybe rename the variable to `lineGap` as it is not a position.

Comment: The method `moveTextPositionByAmount(float tx, float ty)` is deprecated (since version 2.0.xx?). 
Use `newLineAtOffset(float, float)` instead.